# When truffle migrate required account to be unlocked?

Tags: truffle, private-blockchain, truffle-migration, truffle-deployment

I've done several deployment using truffle, but it didn't ask me to unlock the account while deploying the contract on my private chain. But recently I have done one deployment and it asked me to unlock the account.

I was showing this error: `Error: authentication needed: password or unlock`

So, I'm wondering, in which case it asks to unlock the account and when it won't ask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your network config in your `truffle-config.js` ([doc](https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/reference/configuration#networks)), you probably use an account (or the default account) that is on your node. You have to unlock it on your node first to interact with it.

Or you could use an hdwallet provider ([repo here](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/tree/develop/packages/hdwallet-provider)) but it will probably need some eth to make transaction unless you accept `gasPrice: 0` transactions.